# What does `total` in the /notifications route represent?

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, notifications

What does `total` in [/notifications](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/notifications) represent?
I ran it.
The result was `items` in [Common Wrapper Object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper) was array of 24 `items` where as `total` was 4.

Comment: Did you run the function & see?

Comment: Change the `filter`

Comment: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging

Comment: Why did you give me that link. I know it already. Can you see it here - http://i.stack.imgur.com/gpXxx.png?

Comment: I couldn't understand that. There also I am getting same behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug. I've tagged your question accordingly.

**`total`, in [the wrapper object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper), should always be the length of the `items` array, after concatenating all pages of results.**

When I run [/2.2/notifications?pagesize=100&filter=!*L6X1NqVdlFobvlv](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/notifications#page=4&pagesize=100&filter=!*L6X1NqVdlFobvlv), I get 4 pages of results, currently totaling 382 items:

[image: "Totally" Bogus!]

`total` remains fixed at 77.  This is clearly a bug, `total` should be 382 in my case.

Comment: I think they may be telling about the types of `notification_type`.

Comment: No, [there are only 15 `notification_type`s](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/notification).

Comment: I meant in your response. How many types of `notification_type`s are in your response?

Comment: In my particular response there were 6 types of `notification_type` returned. What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: I was guessing. Why do `total` = 4 comes when `items` != 4?

Comment: Why? Because it's a bug!  There could be a mistake in the SQL, or an uninitialized variable, or any of a hundred things that can cause it.  Only someone with developer access could know for sure.